Quick way to create central file in ACC from APS API
I'm finding a API can easier to move around 100 files central download from diffrence project storage in local computer to new project, and what we are doing manual here is oepn Revit and save central one by one for each file.

Open Revit
Open File
Save as to Central belong to new project.
Do loop for more than 100 models.
Do we have any API provied from Autodesk Platform Services can automation do that ?

Any help is appreciated !

you can use Data Management API for uploading files, here's the tutorial for uploading a file.
Since you're getting started I encourage you to complete our official tutorial on Hubs browser to understand basic workflow, then you can do the upload automation, this sample has upload functionality to ACC/BIM360 hubs.
sample source code.

Hi @varunpatil, upload a file can't make it become central file, how we make it become central file work sharing can open inside revit ?

what do you mean by central file? like Revit workshare? i believe you can also access BIM/ACC files from Revit plugins. I'm not sure what is a central file in your context

I mean is model can show in project list after you open from Revit software to collaborate

sorry, I don't understand. Can you please explain the workflow? i didn't understand your third point fully(Save as to Central belong to new project.), I assumed it to be synced with ACC docs.

yes, it can upload to ACC docs, but when you open from Revit software, you can't see it, it look like a local file.

i think you can explore in appstore(https://apps.autodesk.com/en)
https://apps.autodesk.com/BIM360/en/Detail/Index?id=2735608703734729005&appLang=en&os=Web https://apps.autodesk.com/BIM360/en/Detail/Index?id=904446165577977781&appLang=en&os=Web

It look like how you can create a worksharing file without revit software ?

no, I meant there could be Revit plugins to load files from ACC and sync, multiple people can access and sync files.
